# Adding components to both JFrame and it's JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am kind of new to Java, I tried finding an answer for hours but I couldn't.
The problem is pretty simple - I create an array of `JButton` components, and add them to a `JFrame` using:

```
m_Parent.add(this);
```

And it works.

The problem is, I want the same array to appear in a `JInternalFrame` I created in the frame. But when I add:

```
m_Parent.Internal.add(this);
```

It **only** shows up in the internal frame, and no longer appears in the frame.
Why does this happen? how can I make it appear in both frames?

Comment: A component can only have a single parent. So you can't add the same component to two different containers. So you need to create two separate arrays of buttons.

Comment: As has been asked and answered previously, a Swing component can be added to one and only one container. If you need to add it to multiple, then consider creating a factory method that creates the component that you wish to add to multiple locations.